# maven clean deletes target. This then screws up a normal build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I get no errors, however the class files are no longer copied to target directory ("/WEB-INF/classes/...") when doing my next normal (non clean) build.

Thanks muchly for any help, I am learning maven.

When I say normal build, I am using war:war from within eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running `mvn war:war`, you don't run the normal maven life cycle, which beyond others includes the classes compilation. So basically you have no compiled classes to be added to `WEB-INF/classes` since you didn't compile them.

Just run `mvn install` and it should work.

Comment: aaahh. Great thanks, I still don't completely understand it though. Doing install, then build works fine. I don't understand why install is needed this one time after a clean ?

Comment: When you run clean, it deletes all target folder, including all compiled classes. When you run install, it runs all goals in the life cycle before that (including compile, test, package). When you run war:war you run only war creation task, without the other goals. So after clean you don't have compiled classes anymore. But after install you have them, so you can run war:war and it will work. Pay attention that if you change any code and run war:war, the war will be created with the OLD code WITHOUT your change.

Comment: @Tarlog, "war will be created with the OLD code WITHOUT your change" thats not the case, I just tested it ... After doing install, the build war:war works as I expect; changes to *.java are copied across to target "*.class".

Comment: Yes, well, Eclipse did it for you. Not Maven. Try to change the java in some text editor and see that nothing will happen.

Comment: Er, what ? How did eclipse do it for me ? you mean it runs "maven install" in the background ?

Comment: Check in Project menu, do you have Build Automatically enabled?

Comment: Yes, but I assumed that just did build ... its obviosuly doesn't ?

Comment: It automatically compiles files you change.

Comment: whats the best method of just using maven then - you would use "maven install" everytime you changed a "*.java" file ?

Comment: Its nothing to do with build automatically, I just switched it off. and war:war copies .java to the target directory, as I would expect.

Comment: > whats the best method of just using maven then - you would use "maven install" everytime you changed a "*.java" file ?  - Basically yes, it's exactly what I do.

Comment: "Its nothing to do with build automatically" - weird. What happens if you close Eclipse and modify it using the text editor?

Comment: My mistake. It copies a new version across of a single file if I delete the compiled class version of that file; but if I just make changes to a source file it does not update to the new version.  OK thanks. Coming from ant it doesn't make much sense, but guess I will get used to running install all the time.

Answer (score 1):

mvn clean is supposed to cleanup the target directory as per the clean lifecycle phase. You have to compile the source again using compile plugin.

You can use **mvn clean compile war:war** to create the war.

Or you can invoke the default lifecyle by running **mvn install**

Answer (score 0):

I find it's helpful to give Eclipse builds a separate directory from Maven CLI builds:

Insert the following into your pom.xml. The existence of the "m2e.version" property will activate the following profile which alters the location of the Eclipse build

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>IDE</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>m2e.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <!-- Put the IDE's build output in a folder other than target, so that IDE builds don't interact with Maven builds -->
      <directory>target-ide</directory>
    </build>
</profile>
```